# Force Postgresql server to use TLS only

Tags: postgresql

Given the Poodle vulnerabilities in SSLv3 I am trying to configure my Postgresql servers to only use TLS Ciphers.  I can't seem to find anything that would indicate a means to force TLS.

I attempted to change the 
ssl_ciphers  in postgresql.conf to specify the full cipher suite e.g.
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

But that just causes the server to not start at all

Comment: It'd be helpful to see what kind of error message postgres gives when it fails to start (if you're starting Postgres through some init script, sometimes such error messages get hidden). The ssl_ciphers GUC isn't terribly well documented by Postgres, but looking at https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#cipher_strings I have a hunch that only those strings are considered valid. Perhaps try with 'TLSv1' and/or 'TLSv1.2'? BTW, this question would better fit on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You left out  vital information: the exact config file line you added/changed and your PostgreSQL version. Most imporantly **the exact text of the error message from the PostgreSQL log file when it fails to start**. Please *edit your question* then add a comment here when done so I see your change.